# jQuery script not affecting my elements WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site. It has Buddypress installed, with profile search on a sidebar added via a widget called "Buddypress profile search".

I am trying to show different select dropdown based on other dropdowns value. I can get the code to work just fine on Jsfiddle.net. But when i try to add it to my files, it does not affect my elements at all. I've tried to load the script multiple times and multiple places but it just wont work.

My HTML:

```
<select name="field_11" id="field_11">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Counter Strike : Global Offensive">Counter Strike : Global Offensive</option>
<option value="Diablo 3">Diablo 3</option>
<option value="League of Legends">League of Legends</option>
<option value="World of Warcraft">World of Warcraft</option>
<option value="Overwatch">Overwatch</option>
</select>

<select name="field_118" id="field_118">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Casual">Casual</option>
<option value="Mediocre">Mediocre</option>
<option value="Hardcore">Hardcore</option>
<option value="Ready for Esports">Ready for Esports</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
 jQuery("#field_118").hide();
    jQuery("#field_11").change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "Diablo 3") {
            jQuery("#field_118").show();
        } else {
            jQuery("#field_118").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Why can't i get this to work on a sidebar in WordPress?

Comment: Did you enque your file in the functions.php? Where did you add this code to? Did you try to add this directly to the sidebar.php?? That will not work - you have to either enque this script in the functions.php and specify jquery as a dependency or you need to add this in your footer.php file after get_footer although that is not the recommended way...

Comment: @Radmation Yes i did add it like this:
wp_register_script( 'dropdown-remove', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/dropdown-remove.js', array('jquery'),KLEO_THEME_VERSION, true );

Still won't do anything to my html elements.

Comment: @Radmation I have also tried to do it this way:
wp_enqueue_script('dropdown-remove', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/dropdown-remove.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

That "kinda" seems to work. But it only execute the .hide(); in jQuery. It just hides my elements, but the "show/hide" feature still wont work.

Comment: Ya you want to enqueue it not register it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery("#field_118").hide();

    jQuery(document).on("change","#field_11",function () {          
            if (jQuery(this).val() == "Diablo 3") {
                jQuery("#field_118").show();
            } else {
                jQuery("#field_118").hide();
            }
    });

});
```